# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined pug

Tags: html, pug

I wrote this code and I get the error jade iteration: cannot read property 'length' of undefined trying to send data to pug view and i cannot read it because it's wrong

```js
app.get('/about', (req, res)=>{
  var partners =[
    { "name":"Name1", "image": "img1.jpg" },
    { "name": "Name2", "image": "img2.jpg" },
    {"name":"Name3", "image": "img3.jpg" }
  ];

  let lang = getLang(req, res, ['about']);

  res.render('about', {partners , ...lang});
});
```

```html
extends layout

block content
  .subhead
    h2= about.title

  .content.about
    for item in about.team
      div.team
        h3
          span= item[0]
          small= item[1]
        p= item[2]
  each partner in partners
     li.swiper-slide
       img(src=partner.image, alt=partner.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the error that comes up when the pug template isn't being passed the variable properly.  I'd bet that your node server isn't properly interpreting your "new" JSON syntax.

Use this more basic JSON instead and it will work:

```
res.render('about', {
  "partners": partners,
  "lang": lang
});
```