# Cannot read property 'call' of undefined NODE PUG

Tags: node.js, json, pug

I mean that question you can't read the 'length' property of indefinite pug [Cannot read property 'length' of undefined pug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438886/cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-pug)

I added that code in index.js and ran npm i and npm start so that when displayed locally the 'call' property of undefined

I tried to install nodemon because I need to stop the project running npm i and running npm star, I also removed the project and re-downloaded the project as I had before I had the problem of not reading the property.

In other words add in the code what they suggested and I now got this error of cannot read property, without that I was great

```
JS
app.get('/about', (req, res)=>{
  var partners =[
    { "name":"Calvin Froedge", "image": "calvin-linkedin.jpg" },
    { "name": "Joel Arberman", "image": "joel-linkedin.jpg" },
    {"name":"Kirt Barker", "image": "Kirt Barker" }
  ];

  let lang = getLang(req, res, ['about']);

  res.render('about', {
    "partners": partners,
    "lang": lang
  });
});
```

```
pug
extends layout

block content
  .subhead
    h2= about.title

  .content.about
    for item in about.team
      div.team
        h3
          span= item[0]
          small= item[1]
        p= item[2]
  each partner in partners
     li.swiper-slide
       img(src=partner.image, alt=partner.name)
```